# ReactJS: Using rgba in box-shadow with styled-components props not working

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm building a **ReactJS** site and use **styled-components** with `ThemeProvider`. So my background-color or color css codes are like this `background-color: ${props => (props.theme.background)}`.
Now I want to create a CSS pulse animation with box-shadow.

```
const pulse = keyframes
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }


// My component
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
animation: ${pulse} 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
```

That's working! But I want to use the color from my ThemeProvider so I tried this:

```
// shadow from ThemeProvider = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)";
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 ${props => (props.theme.shadow)};
```

And it's not working this way. I googled it but haven't found any solution for my problem. Can you help? How can I use props with rgba in box-shadow?

**EDIT:** It's working when I use a HEX Code!!! But not rgba and I need rgba!

Comment: Why do you need rgba? If it's a set color that's not gonna be changed (assuming yout theme has a fixed set of colors that is) why don't just use the hex equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, the color function `rgba()` works perfectly with `styled-components`. I have prepared a [**demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/l2vvl67l9q) that assimilates your current implementation. You can go through this and compare with your current output.

Comment: Cool. Didn't know that you can do this that way. Thanks! :)