# Using rgba in box-shadow with styled-components not working

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this code:

```js
const Test = styled.img`
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(27, 31, 36, 0.15);
`;

export default function Avatar(props: AvatarProps): ReactElement {
    return <Test src={props.avatar} alt={props.name} className={props.className} />;
}
```

When I inspect my code on Chromium (100.0.4896.127) I see `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(27 31 36 / 15%);` this not seems a RGBA color or a RGB valid color.

And the same if I inspect the code of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837614/10798494) old Stackoverflow post, I see `box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);`

So, whitch is the correct way to use rgba in box-shadow with styled-components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way the dev tools displays the syntax. It's the same colour, don't worry.